# C++ for loops for taking in input to fill an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I need to make a program that takes in 6 float numbers and eventually I have to sort them from least to greatest in an array, and drop the biggest and smallest number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

bool flag;
float score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6;
int size;
float scoresheet [6] = {score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6};

cout << "Pleaser enter your score for the gymnast: ";
cin >> score1;

while (cin.fail() || score1 > 10 || score1 < 0)
{
    cout << "Invalid score!" << endl;
    cout << "Pleaser enter your score for the gymnast: ";
    cin >> score1;
}
```

This is what I have so far. I know I need to make a for loop but how do I do so, so that after the input is validated, it will assign the 6 inputs to its place in the array 'scoresheet'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to declare (and use) `score1`, `score2`, etc. separately, why bother having a `scoresheet[6]`?

Comment: Take your validation loop, put it in a for loop. Use the array.

Comment: I thought that was the correct way to make an array @R_Kapp

Comment: Assigning the uninitialized scores to initialize the array is undefined behavour. Also, use `<vector>`, not arrays. It's better for your health.

Comment: @DevSolar: this has the smell of schoolwork, and that often means restrictions like "no templates". (Also, `std::array` would perhaps be a better fit than a vector, here!)

Comment: @Rook: I will personally step up to *any* tutor putting a C++ class through restrictions like that and tell him his class material sucks. There is nothing to be won with C arrays, and lots to be lost. But, yes, this smells like homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    array<float,6> myArray;//create and  array of 6 elements
    float number;//to store the individual numbers

    cout << "Please type 6 numbers: ";


    for(size_t i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
        {
           if(i==6){
              break;
           }
           cin >> number;
           myArray[i] = number;//adding the numbers to the array
        }


    cout << "\nUnsorted array:" << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
        cout << myArray [i] << " ";



    cout << "\n\nSorted Array:" << endl;
    sort(myArray.begin(), myArray.end());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
        cout << myArray [i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    //Smallest number
    float smallest = 1000;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(smallest > myArray[i])
            smallest = myArray[i];
    }
    //Biggest number
    float biggest = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(biggest < myArray[i])
            biggest = myArray[i];
    }

    cout << "The Smallest number is: " << smallest << endl;
    cout << "The Biggest number is: " << biggest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The editor *does* let you write the full code, please check my edit. By the way, why are you using `decltype` on `size()`? And what's the purpose of `bool stop;`? You seem to never really use it.